# Test Oracle SQL queries in subset of data in big table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some big tables in an Oracle database, representing transactions etc.

Is there a way in Oracle/SQL to try a query on a subset of the data? Just to speed up the time it takes to try different queries and feel confident that you’ve got the logic right? Once I feel confident that my query is correct I want to run it on the full dataset.

Comment: You can use the `WHERE` clause to filter out rows, can't you?

Comment: you can also use the sampling clause, depending on the complexity of your queries.

Comment: I might recommend taking a subset of the table and stash it to use for testing.  This not only ensures that the data does not change as you fix things, but it also cues the optimizer to take advantage of a smaller table.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Didn’t know about the sampling clause @gsalem. I’ll look in to that! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Using smaller subsets for testing is what I’m doing now. But it’s a pain and requires preparations and cleanups for each case. But of course asu say, a valid and safe approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit your result set by the pseudo column ROWNUM.
In your where clause, add:

```
and rownum < 100  -- or any number you want
```

And this will put a hard stop at that number of rows.

Comment: This just means that the result set will be limited to 100. The query will still run on the entire dataset. Maybe @weenzeel has a huge database?!

Comment: It means it will return the result as soon as it has 100 rows, which will be a lot faster. Otherwise he should be copying out a subset of the data into a mirror table